# How to get out of git in the bash terminal's command line

Tags: bash, git, gnome-terminal, linux-terminal

My terminal's logline (is that the right term?) says I'm in git. How do I exit git?:
[image]

Comment: You don't really. when a git-aware shell has a directory that contains a git repo selected, it will always show you information about the branch and whatnot. git is not a command you "enter/exit", but instead every git command you run starts with `git`. its not like starting an interactive session like you might with ftp or telnet or whatever, where your input is processed by that application. the only application that is processing your input right now is bash (which you can in turn use to invoke git commands).

Comment: note that if you didn't want your home to be a git repository, delete the ~/.git folder. thats what tells the shell that there is a git repo here. you probably accidentally entered `git init` at some point when the working directory was set to ~.

Comment: You're absolutely right, @FrankThomas. If you can turn your comment into a response I can accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end this issue comes down to confusion about what the shell is displaying, but we'll walk through it.

Many OS and shell distributors (or their users) may elect to use a "Git Aware" prompt in their cli shells. These have the effect of displaying information about a git repository that exists in the shell's current working directory or on the path to that working directory. In the image provided with the question, this shell is displaying information about a git repository defined in `/home` or `/home/alan`. Its important to note however that the git application is not currently running, so there is nothing to "exit" from.

Git provides both non-interactive and interactive commands. Most users simply invoke non-interactive git commands that execute and immediately return control to the shell.

While it is not the case here, I'd be remiss if I did not mention that there are several git commands that *can* be used interactively however like `git add -i` which launch in the shell, and continue to run, prompting the user for information on what they want to do.

```
$ git add -i
           staged     unstaged path
  1:    unchanged        +0/-1 TODO
  2:    unchanged        +1/-1 index.html
  3:    unchanged        +5/-1 lib/simplegit.rb

*** Commands ***
  1: [s]tatus     2: [u]pdate      3: [r]evert     4: [a]dd untracked
  5: [p]atch      6: [d]iff        7: [q]uit       8: [h]elp
What now>
```

(source https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging)

In the case above, you would hit `q` to exit the application. If the git interactive command does not offer you a means to quit, that usually indicates that it is not safe to exit the application at this time because there are half-performed operations in-progress (like a conflicted merge where not all conflicts have been resolved).

You also have the option to use a shell method to end the command like `ctrl+c` but that can have unexpected or damaging results under the wrong circumstances. Pressing `Ctrl+c` or killing the shell instance during conflict resolution of a merge will leave your files full of conflict markers like `<<<<<<< HEAD`, `=======`, or `>>>>>>> 77976da35a11db4580b80ae27e8d65caf5208086`, so it can really damage your code files.

But in this case, no git interactive command is running, and there is no need for further concern. if the shell indicates that a undesired git repository exists on a path, the repo can be removed, or the directory can be moved to another path that does not contain a repo. you could probably also add the path to the .gitignore file, though I'm not sure if that will prevent the repo in the parent directory from displaying git-awareness on the prompt.